# JTable and JScrollPane not shown as they should

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Why doesn't this work (doesn't show up in GUI)

```
JTable table=new JTable(20,20);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

JScrollPane tableScrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
tableScrollPane.setBounds(10,70,540,280);
tableScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
tableScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
add(tableScrollPane);
```

Whereas this does(does show up in GUI).

```
JTable table=new JTable(20,20);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

JScrollPane tableScrollPane=new JScrollPane();
tableScrollPane.setBounds(10,70,540,280);
tableScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
tableScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
tableScrollPane.add(table);
add(tableScrollPane);
```

Why is this the case, shouldn't they both do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case, shouldn't they both do the same thing?

No.

A JScrollPane contains many components including the scrollbars and a viewport and uses its own internal layout manager to set the location of each component. You can't just "add" a component to the scroll pane because the layout manager doesn't support this.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How a Scroll Pane Works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#operation) for more information.

The component (in this case, JTable) needs to be added to the "viewport" of the scroll pane.

You can use:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

or

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( );    
scrollPanwe.setViewportView( table );
```